# Why flatten API responses in Node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I've been asked to look at flatting API responses on a Node.js project I'm working on but I'm not entirely sure why it needs to be flattened. No responses are nested beyond 2 levels so to me it's not too bad. Can anybody tell me why an API response would be flattened? I'd be keen to know the pros and cons aswell an hear any suggestions on how to do it? I'm currently looking at npm package `flat`.

Here's an example response:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "John Doe",
           "email": "john@doe.com",
           "suppliers": [
               {
                   "id": 1,
                   "name": "Supplier1",
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Jane Doe",
           "email": "jane@doe.com",
           "suppliers": [
               {
                   "id": 1,
                   "name": "Supplier1",
               },{
                   "id": 2,
                   "name": "Supplier2",
               }
           ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the response that needs to be flattened?  Also, did they give a reason for flattening it?

Comment: I don't think there's a general answer here. I can only speculate as to why you were asked this. I would start by asking them why.

Comment: Yes, I haven't asked yet. It's the first time I've been asked something so wanted to look into it a little first. I added an example response to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid the question, in its original form, does not have the right answer; it is heavily opinion-based. There are, of course, specifications, like [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org), that prescribe certain general schema of response, but there's hardly such a convention that would say, "an API response would be flattened".

Comment: You provided an example response, now, how does a "flattened" response should look like?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody tell me why an API response would be flattened? I'd be
>   keen to know the pros and cons aswell an hear any suggestions on how
>   to do it?

Pros:
An API needs to be flattened if the consumer of that API requires it to be flattened.  For example, if the purpose of the API is to provide data that gets loaded into a table view of some kind, it would be much more convenient to the consumer if the API returned the data flattened to match the shape of that table.

Cons:
Flattening hierarchical data often times requires either limiting the number of child elements that can be returned or creating more rows that makes sense.

Consider your data flattened in these two approaches:

**Flattened approach #1**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "John Doe",
           "email": "john@doe.com",
           "suppliers_1_id": 1,
           "suppliers_1_name": "Supplier1",
           "suppliers_2_id": null,
           "suppliers_2_name": null
        }, {            
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Jane Doe",
           "email": "jane@doe.com",
           "suppliers_1_id": 1,
           "suppliers_1_name": "Supplier1",
           "suppliers_2_id": 2,
           "suppliers_2_name": "Supplier2"               
       }
    ]
}
```

In this example, it has to be decided ahead of time what the maximum number of suppliers that can be returned.  I really dislike this kind of design for storing data, but often it is the requested way for data to be displayed in a table.  If for example there are 3 suppliers for a user, you would have no way to return that data without adding more columns.  It very quickly becomes unmanageable unless you have a very small and finite maximum number of child rows.

**Flattened approach #2**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "John Doe",
           "email": "john@doe.com",
           "supplier_id": 1,
           "supplier_name": "Supplier1"
       }, {     
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Jane Doe",
           "email": "jane@doe.com",
           "supplier_id": 1,
           "supplier_name": "Supplier1"        
       }, {     
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Jane Doe",
           "email": "jane@doe.com",
           "supplier_id": 2,
           "supplier_name": "Supplier2"               
       }
    ]
}
```

This approach simply repeats each user for the number of suppliers.  This format is convenient for making it possible to convert the flattened data back to hierarchical data.  It is a common approach when retrieving  hierarchical data from a relational database in a single rowset.  A client application can easily reassemble the original hierarchy by grouping by user id.  The negative to this approach is it returns more than one row per top-level object, which can cause larger data payloads.  If you have a single, internal consumer of the API, this approach may work.  If it is for a public API, you'll have to spend more time documenting and supporting the API, because it may not make sense to your API consumers.

> I'm not entirely sure why it needs to be flattened.

Whoever is asking you to flatten it should specify that actual shape they are looking for, and that may provide clarity.  I've described two possible ways to flatten your data, but there are plenty more possibilities.

Comment: Approach #1 would not be recommended.  To use it, one would have to dynamically create supplier property names which you then test for.  That's way less friendly than just putting the suppliers in an array.  So, that way of flattening the suppliers is definitely worse to use than the array.  A list of suppliers should be in an array.

Comment: Whether approach #2 makes any sense depends upon how a typical consumer of the API will use the response.  Approach #2 is less efficient in terms of data transfered (lots of duplicate data), but if the consumer of the API most likely wants an array of users/supplier objects like approach #2 suppliers then this approach might be easier to consume (even though it's more verbose in terms of data transferred).  So, it really depends upon what a typical consumer of the API would be doing with the response.